# How to add an icon to actiontab

Tags: android

Hi I have followed the tutorial below exactly and now I'm wondering how I can add an icon to each tab? I only know how to add an icon to a menu but not a tab. Also I'm new to android, so it would be awsome if someone could tell me **exactly** where the `android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_view_as_list"` should go.

As it is now it is only adding the Text with the argument `ActionBar.Tab tabB = bar.newTab().setText("Summary");` but I also want for example tabB to have the `android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_view_as_list"`

[here is the tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMu8XhxUBl8)

[and here](http://www.abelski.com/courses/android3ui/actionbar.pdf)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
ActionBar.Tab tabB = bar.newTab()
.setText("Summary")
.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_view_as_list);;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Android")
                .setTabListener(new AndroidFragment())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.android);

        actionBar.addTab(tab);

    }
}
```